# How can I configure multiple databases with springboot one being JPA and the other 5 plain jdbc?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, jdbc, multiple-databases

For a project with a springboot backend, I have to use 1 database in Postgresql to save information and to add a history feature to the application and 5 other databases in Oracle on which I only have readonly access on views. For those 5 I only have to get ponctual values and the databases are huge so it doesn't make sense to have repositories and entities. But I can't find any information on how to configure multiple databases if one uses ORM and the others don't.

application.properties

```
#informations for the history database
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/NA_db
spring.datasource.username = userNA
spring.datasource.password = userNApwd
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema: always
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

DataSourceConfiguration.java

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "historyEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "historyTransactionManager", basePackages = "mypackage.history.dao")
@EntityScan("mypackage.history.model.entities")
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties SourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "historyDatasource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.configuration")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return SourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();

    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "historyEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean barEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("historyDatasource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("mypackage.history.model.entities")
                .persistenceUnit("historyPU").build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "historyTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager barTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("historyEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory barEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(barEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Connection and Statement creation for the other databases

```
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            connectionYG = DriverManager.getConnection(urlYG, user, password);
            stmtYG = connectionYG.createStatement();
            connectionZA = DriverManager.getConnection(urlZA, user, password);
            stmtZA = connectionZA.createStatement();
            connectionZB = DriverManager.getConnection(urlZB, user, password);
            stmtZB = connectionZB.createStatement();
            connectionZC = DriverManager.getConnection(urlZC, user, password);
            stmtZC = connectionZC.createStatement();
            connectionZD = DriverManager.getConnection(urlZD, user, password);
            stmtZD = connectionZD.createStatement();
```

Here is what I tried with a configuration class for the history database and instantiation of the connections directly where I need them in my service class.

Here is what I get :

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

I am pretty sure I just don't configurate my databases the correct way but I can't find the correct informations. Have you any ideas on how am I supposed to do ?